# How to set time for repeating alarm for every 15 mints in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I have created two back ground services in my application. I have to start my back ground service with in some intervals. So I am using alarm for this. One service have to start for every 15 minutes and another one for once per day. My code is here.

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);

        pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);;

        i=15;                                 
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), i*1000, pintent);

         if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) 
         {

                startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), TestService.class));

         }
        else
        {


        }
```

I used like this. Its works finely in first time. Which means my alarm starts again after 15 mints in first time. Then it repeating for every 15 seconds. I don't know how to set the time properly for this. Can any body tell me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: when receiver detect alarm set new alarm after 15min

Comment: refer this http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

Comment: You are using 15*1000 = 15000 milliseconds = 15 seconds time inter val , Update it to 15*60*1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes+15);//
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

> change this line...

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), i*1000, pintent);
```

to

> long repeatingTime=15*60*1000;

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),repeatingTime, pintent);
```